# Variadic arguments (va_arg) and its default type

Tags: c++, c++17

When I use `printf` to print a `std::string` on the screen I need to use `"%s"` and `c_str()` function. I'd like to create a class that inherits from `std::string` and by default returns value of `c_str` like in the example below:

```
class String : public std::string
{
    public:

        using std::string::string;

        operator const char *() const
        {
            return c_str();
        }
};

...

String s = "abc";
printf("%s\n", abc);
```

It won't work as `operator const char *()` is not applied for the type of `...` that is used in `printf` function. Any ideas how to do this? `const void *'` doesn't work either.

Comment: "*I'd like to create a class that inherits from std::string and by default returns value of c_str*" No, you *really* don't want a string type that implicitly converts to `char const*`.

Comment: The standard library types are not to designed to be used as base classes. If you want to extend them use composition, or just create functions accepting a const std::string&.

Comment: Don't use C style variadic functions.  C++ now has variadic templates, which work inside the type system.  C++20 also comes with `fmt` that will let you have `printf` like functionality with full type support.